# How to install a specific version of php 7.1.28 on Amzon Linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, php-7.1, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I need to install the 7.1.28 version of php in my EC2 instance, and i have to install also php-mysqlnd
and php opcache, i added the remi repository but i get the 7.1.33, there is any repository or any guide for do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Old versions can be download manually, but no repository, as these versions are EOL and their usage strongly discouraged.

Comment: yes i know this versions are EOL and can be downloaded mannually. i was asking how to do it couse i having some problems, there is a best pratice for do it?

Comment: I mean download manually from the repository  online  archive, you can ask on dedicated forum https://forum.remirepo.net/viewforum.php?id=6  for ex: http://rpms.remirepo.net/store/php/common/7.1.28/